# Should I import both module and submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I am using `logging` library in python 3. I want to use `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`, `logging.Formatter` and `logging.getLogger` in my code.

What I have observed is that following (ignore the parameters to the functions) works without any errors:

```
import logging.handlers
log_formatter = logging.Formatter()
log_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler()
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

In such case should I also import `logging` separately?
Also, does importing submodule always import all the references from parent modules in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Usually*, importing a module does import all of its parents, and doesn't import any of its submodules. If you implement everything in pure Python, and don't do anything funky, that's how it works.

But extension modules may work differently. (For example, if you `import os`, you get `os.path`.)

And pure Python code *can* do funky things—e.g., instead of a real package layout on disk, you can write a top-level module that dynamically builds the package, in which case users will have to `import` that top-level module first (and may or may not get the submodules for free).

It's *always* safe to explicitly `import` everything you're going to use directly. And there's no real harm in doing so—an extra line of code, a few nanoseconds for the importer to see that the module is already in the dict and do nothing, that's about it.

And meanwhile, it's clear to the human reader—and to an IDE that doesn't actually do the `import`s. When you call `logging.getLogger`, I can see that you did `import logger`, so I know that `logging` is a module, not some other global.

But if you really want to, you can learn how each specific package works and use that knowledge. Going in this direction is rarely confusing in practice. And, even in the opposite direction, a lot of real-world code does rely on `import os` giving you `os.path`.

In the particular case of `logging`, I believe all of the examples in the tutorial and cookbook in the docs explicitly `import logging`, so if you're asking what's most idiomatic, it's probably that.

Comment: I was actually looking for what is usually done in such cases. So i'll include logging now. Also, thanks for the explanation.